# Random sampling list of arrays

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list of arrays, e.g.:

`list = (array[a1,a2,a3],array[b1,b2,b3],array[c1,c2,c3])`

Now, I would like to take a random sample from each array in the list, for example: `a1, b3,c1`

What is the best way to code this?

Comment: What do you mean by a list of arrays? What you have written down is not a valid Python literal (although it is *almost* a tuple of numpy arrays) Beyond that, a list comprehension using `random.choice()` seems natural. What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: don't use `list`as a name of a list.

Comment: I indeed tried `code`random.sample()`code` as:
`code`
inds = []
for i in range(len(list)):
 r = random.sample(list[i])
inds.append(r)
`code`

In this case it randomly selects one full array, but instead I want 1 value from each array in the list. It might be a very beginner mistake... sorry about that

P.s. the variable names are purily as an example since the real list is a lot larger

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import sample 
list2 = [['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2','b3'],['c1','c2','c3']]
print([sample(x,1)[0] for x in list2])
```

This will result in

```
['a3', 'b3', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will work.

```
import random
list1 = (['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2','b3'],['c1','c2','c3'])
list2= []
for e in list1:
    list2.append(random.choice(e))
print(list2)
```